# Trailing character error with vim.api.nvim_command

Tags: neovim, nvchad

I have hard times figuring out what is wrong with these lines I am writing in my init.lua file in Neovim:

```
vim.cmd "cd C:/Users/samue/Desktop/"      
vim.api.nvim_command "<Space>e"
vim.api.nvim_command "<C-w>w"
vim.api.nvim_command ":vsplit"
vim.api.nvim_command ":terminal"
vim.api.nvim_command "<C-w>W"
```

Anything I write after '<' is said to be erroneous trailing stuff upon NV startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nvim_command` is to run `Ex` command (i.e. command that starts with `:`).

If you want to simulate character you can use the execute and normal command:

```
vim.api.nvim_command 'execute "normal" "\\<Space>e"'
```

But my advise is to stick with `Ex` commands:

```
vim.cmd "cd ~/Desktop" 
vim.cmd "NvimTreeOpen"
vim.cmd "wincmd w"
vim.cmd "vsplit"
vim.cmd "terminal"
vim.cmd "wincmd w"
```

You can also use a multi-line Lua string like in:

```
vim.cmd([[
cd ~/Desktop 
NvimTreeOpen
wincmd w
vsplit
terminal
wincmd w
]])
```

Comment: What is the diff between Ed and Ex then?

Comment: also the diff between vim.cmd and vim.api.nvim_command?

Comment: My mistake I meant `Ex`.

Comment: OK. So your solution does not work :( I get invalid escape sequence near 'execute "normal"

Comment: According to the [doc](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_command()) the later is more to execute a complete script and not only one command.

Comment: My mistake I forgot one `\` :-|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143030/discussion-between-vivian-de-smedt-and-samuelnihoul).

Comment: Hi @samuelnihoul, do you still have the problem? If the solution fit your need maybe could you validate it using the v green box next to the arrow voting button. It help the question to rest :-)

Comment: @samuelnihoul, do you have still the problem? What should we add to have the solution validated?